# Rust CSV Sorter Code Lookover

Tags: beginner, csv, rust

I am new to Rust, began learning a few days ago. I have written a simple csv_sorter based off of one I had written for a class previously. Everything runs fine and I have gotten my expected results. I do not know all of the Rust conventions, and am unsure what I may be doing wrong, or what can be done differently.

Would anyone be willing to review my code? Please point out any bad design, poor optimizations, or alternative ideas. (Note, I still want to follow the structure of file > struct > list > output https://github.com/HammerAPI/rustcode/tree/master/csv_sorter

````
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};
use std::process;


// Person struct to hold relevant data
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip_code: String,
}

// Person constructor
impl Person {
    fn new(first_name: String, last_name: String,
            street: String, city: String, state: String,
            zip_code: String) -> Person {

        Person {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            street,
            city,
            state,
            zip_code,
        }
    }
}




/**
 * Processes command-line arguments
 *
 * # Description
 * This function processes the passed-in command line arguments and attempts
 * to open and create valid input/output files from the names given.
 *
 * # Arguments
 * * `args` - A string array of command-line arguments.
 *
 * # Returns
 * * A tuple of the input file and output file if they are found, else errors.
 */
fn arg_parser(args: &[String]) -> Result<(File, File), &'static str> {

    // Exit if too many or too few arguments were passed
    if args.len() != 3 {
        return Err("Usage: 'cargo run [input file] [output file]");
    }

    // Get the input file
    let input_file = match File::open(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[1])) {
        Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't open file: {}", why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Get the output file
    let output_file = match File::create(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[2])) {
        Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't create file: {}", why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Return both files as a tuple
    Ok((input_file, output_file))
}




/**
 * Builds a list of Person structs
 *
 * # Description
 * This function reads the input file line by line and creates a Person
 * struct based on the line's contents. It then adds that struct to a vector
 * and repeats for every line in the file. The final vector contains every
 * Person struct read in from the file.
 *
 * # Arguments
 * * `input_file` - The input file to read from.
 *
 * # Returns
 * * A vector of type Person containing all Person structs from the file.
 */
fn build_person_vec(input_file: &mut File) -> Vec<Person> {

    let mut person_vec: Vec<Person> = Vec::new();
    let reader = BufReader::new(input_file);

    for line in reader.lines() {

        let line = line.unwrap();

        let data: Vec<&str> = line.split(", ").collect();

        let p = Person::new(String::from(data[0].trim()),
                            String::from(data[1].trim()),
                            String::from(data[2].trim()),
                            String::from(data[3].trim()),
                            String::from(data[4].trim()),
                            String::from(data[5].trim()));
        person_vec.push(p);
    }
    person_vec
}




/**
 * Sorts the list of Person structs
 *
 * # Description
 * Sorts via Selection Sort.
 *
 * # Arguments
 * * `person_vec` - A vector containing Person structs.
 */
fn sort_person_vec(person_vec: &mut Vec<Person>) {

    for i in 0..person_vec.len() {

        let mut lowest = i;

        for j in (i + 1)..person_vec.len() {

            // Temporary variables to hold first and last names
            let j_last = &person_vec[j].last_name.to_lowercase();
            let j_first = &person_vec[j].first_name.to_lowercase();
            let low_last = &person_vec[lowest].last_name.to_lowercase();
            let low_first = &person_vec[lowest].first_name.to_lowercase();

            // Swap by last name or first name if last names are equal
            if (j_last < low_last) || (j_last == low_last && j_first < low_first){
                lowest = j;
            }
        }
        person_vec.swap(lowest, i);
    }
}




/**
 * Writes data to the output file
 *
 * # Description
 * Writes all Person structs to the output file, catching errors if the file
 * is not available to be written to.
 *
 * # Arguments
 * * `person_vec` - A vector containing Person structs.
 * * `output_file` - The file to write to.
 */
fn write_to_file(person_vec: &mut Vec<Person>, output_file: &mut File) {

    for p in person_vec {

        // Format the peron's information as a string
        let info = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
            p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city,
            p.state, p.zip_code);

        // Write to output file
        match output_file.write_all(info.as_bytes()) {
            Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't write to file: {}", why),
            Ok(_) => (),
        }
    }
}




fn main() {

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // Get the input and output files
    let (mut input_file, mut output_file) = arg_parser(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("\nError: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });

    let mut person_vec = build_person_vec(&mut input_file);

    sort_person_vec(&mut person_vec);

    write_to_file(&mut person_vec, &mut output_file);
}```
````

Comment: Not worth an additional answer, but your comments on `struct Person` and `impl Person` are not doc-comments (use `///` for those), also the one on `impl Person` actually seems to apply only to `Person::new`, so should be moved there.

Comment: Also, your block doc-comments aren't parsed correctly by VS Code/rust-analyzer. Not sure if it's a bug or if your formatting isn't valid.

Answer (score 6):

From my limited Rust knowledge:  (I'm a beginner too; let's learn together)

## Compilation

I had to add `use std::env` to compile the code.  Is that a copy-paste error?

## Formatting

Your code deviates from the official [Rust Style Guide](https://github.com/rust-dev-tools/fmt-rfcs/blob/master/guide/guide.md) in a few aspects:

- Separate items and statements by either zero or one blank lines (i.e., one or two newlines).  ([Blank lines](https://github.com/rust-dev-tools/fmt-rfcs/blob/master/guide/guide.md#blank-lines))
- Indentation of function parameters / arguments:

  ```
  -    fn new(first_name: String, last_name: String,
  -            street: String, city: String, state: String,
  -            zip_code: String) -> Person {
  -
  +    fn new(
  +        first_name: String,
  +        last_name: String,
  +        street: String,
  +        city: String,
  +        state: String,
  +        zip_code: String,
  +    ) -> Person {
  ```

  ```
  -        let p = Person::new(String::from(data[0].trim()),
  -                            String::from(data[1].trim()),
  -                            String::from(data[2].trim()),
  -                            String::from(data[3].trim()),
  -                            String::from(data[4].trim()),
  -                            String::from(data[5].trim()));
  +        let p = Person::new(
  +            String::from(data[0].trim()),
  +            String::from(data[1].trim()),
  +            String::from(data[2].trim()),
  +            String::from(data[3].trim()),
  +            String::from(data[4].trim()),
  +            String::from(data[5].trim()),
  +        );
  ```

  ```
  -        let info = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
  -            p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city,
  -            p.state, p.zip_code);
  +        let info = format!(
  +            "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
  +            p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city, p.state, p.zip_code
  +        );
  ```
- Spacing before `{`:

  ```
  -            if (j_last < low_last) || (j_last == low_last && j_first < low_first){
  +            if (j_last < low_last) || (j_last == low_last && j_first < low_first) {
  ```

You can apply these formatting guidelines by running `rustfmt`.  (I found these by using `rustfmt --check`, which prints a diff.)

## Constructor

In my opinion, `Person::new` is unnecessary.  This:

```
Person::new(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

is not more readable than

```
Person {
    first_name: a,
    last_name: b,
    street: c,
    city: d,
    state: e,
    zip_code: f,
}
```

## `Result::expect`

These `match` expressions:

> ```
> // Get the input file
> let input_file = match File::open(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[1])) {
>     Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't open file: {}", why),
>     Ok(file) => file,
> };
>
> // Get the output file
> let output_file = match File::create(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[2])) {
>     Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't create file: {}", why),
>     Ok(file) => file,
> };
> ```

can be simplified with [`Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect):

```
let input_file = File::open(format!("src/{}", &args[1])).expect("Couldn't open file");
let output_file = File::create(format!("src/{}", &args[2])).expect("Couldn't create file");
```

Similarly:

> ```
> // Write to output file
> match output_file.write_all(info.as_bytes()) {
>     Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't write to file: {}", why),
>     Ok(_) => (),
> }
> ```

becomes

```
output_file
    .write_all(info.as_bytes())
    .expect("Couldn't write to file");
```

Note that `expect` uses `fmt::Debug` to print the error information.  If you want to use `fmt::Display` (as your original code does), you can use `unwrap_or_else` instead of `expect`, per [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241636/rust-csv-sorter-code-lookover/241640#comment474227_241640):

```
.unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Couldn't open file: {}", err))
```

## Sorting

You can reinventing the wheel here:

> ```
> fn sort_person_vec(person_vec: &mut Vec<Person>) {
>     for i in 0..person_vec.len() {
>         let mut lowest = i;
>
>         for j in (i + 1)..person_vec.len() {
>             // Temporary variables to hold first and last names
>             let j_last = &person_vec[j].last_name.to_lowercase();
>             let j_first = &person_vec[j].first_name.to_lowercase();
>             let low_last = &person_vec[lowest].last_name.to_lowercase();
>             let low_first = &person_vec[lowest].first_name.to_lowercase();
>
>             // Swap by last name or first name if last names are equal
>             if (j_last < low_last) || (j_last == low_last && j_first < low_first) {
>                 lowest = j;
>             }
>         }
>         person_vec.swap(lowest, i);
>     }
> }
> ```

The lexical comparison feature of tuples can be used here:

```
fn sort_person_vec(person_vec: &mut Vec<Person>) {
    person_vec.sort_by_key(|person| {
        (
            person.last_name.to_lowercase(),
            person.first_name.to_lowercase(),
        )
    });
}
```

## `eprintln!`

This:

> ```
> println!("\nError: {}", err);
> ```

shouldn't be printed to `stderr`:

```
eprintln!("\nError: {}", err);
```

## Error handling

Consider validating the data in `build_person_vec`.

Comment: It should be noted that `.expect("Couldn't open file")` will format the error using `fmt::Debug`, not `fmt::Display` like the original code. If you want to stick with `fmt::Display`, you could do `.unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Couldn't open file: {}", err))` instead (still better than the match).

Comment: @Joe Thanks.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. The parenthetical "(as `panic!` does)" isn't quite correct, as `panic!` will use the format you specify (i.e., with `{:?}` instead of `{}` it would also use `fmt::Display`

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I've fixed that.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed response. This is all incredibly helpful information, and your statements are crystal clear. I had no idea about `rustfmt` ! 
And yes, the `use std::env;` was a copy paste error- my bad!

Answer (score 2):

As always, I recommend using [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy#as-a-cargo-subcommand-cargo-clippy) for help. Running it, we get the following output:

```
warning: you seem to be trying to use match for destructuring a single pattern. Consider using `if let`
   --> src/main.rs:188:9
    |
188 | /         match output_file.write_all(info.as_bytes()) {
189 | |             Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't write to file: {}", why),
190 | |             Ok(_) => (),
191 | |         }
    | |_________^ help: try this: `if let Err(why) = output_file.write_all(info.as_bytes()) { panic!("\ncouldn't write to file: {}", why) }`
```

So that's the first change we can make.

```
/**
 * # CSV Sorter
 *
 * ## Author: Daniel Hammer
 *
 * ### Date: 2020/5/2
 *
 * ### Description:
 * This program reads in a CSV composed of information about people, such as
 * names and addresses. It then stores each entry into a struct, and those
 * structs into a vector. The vector is sorted by last name (or first, if
 * last names are identical) and the newly sorted data is written to an
 * output file.
 */
```

For module-level documentation, use `//!` instead of `/**`.

```
fn arg_parser(args: &[String]) -> Result<(File, File), &'static str> {
```

You really shouldn't return strings as your error type—they don't implement [Error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), so they don't play nicely with other stuff. Use an error handling crate instead, such as anyhow (or implement it yourself).

```
// Person constructor
impl Person {
    fn new(first_name: String, last_name: String,
           street: String, city: String, state: String,
           zip_code: String) -> Person {

        Person {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            street,
            city,
            state,
            zip_code,
        }
    }
}
```

`// Person constructor` is a useless comment. Remove it. And for that matter, there's no need for a constructor like this at all—and it's hard to remember the parameter order. Just fill in the `Person` struct manually.

```
    let input_file = match File::open(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[1])) {
        Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't open file: {}", why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Get the output file
    let output_file = match File::create(format!("{}{}", "src/", &args[2])) {
        Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't create file: {}", why),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };
```

Don't format paths like that, use [Path::join](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) instead.

```
let data: Vec<&str> = line.split(", ").collect();
```

You don't need to allocate a vector for that, just use Iterators directly (see my final code for my implementation).

```
fn sort_person_vec(person_vec: &mut [Person]) {
```

Just implement `Ord` on `Person` so you can just call `person_vec.sort()`.

```
/**
 * Writes data to the output file
 *
 * # Description
 * Writes all Person structs to the output file, catching errors if the file
 * is not available to be written to.
 *
 * # Arguments
 * * `person_vec` - A vector containing Person structs.
 * * `output_file` - The file to write to.
 */
fn write_to_file(person_vec: &mut Vec<Person>, output_file: &mut File) {

    for p in person_vec {

        // Format the peron's information as a string
        let info = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
                           p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city,
                           p.state, p.zip_code);

        // Write to output file
        match output_file.write_all(info.as_bytes()) {
            Err(why) => panic!("\ncouldn't write to file: {}", why),
            Ok(_) => (),
        }
    }
}
```

Rust uses `///` documentation comments (vs `//!` for modules), not `/**`. When you run `cargo doc` or publish your crate, this documentation won't get carried over. It's also not common to use a Description header in Rust, as that's implied. And there's no need to say what each argument is if that's all you're gonna say: it's obvious that the parameter `person_vec` of type `&mut Vec<Person>` is a `Vec` of `Person`s. Additionally, there's no need for `person_vec` to be mutable, or even a `Vec` at all. Instead, you should accept a `&[Person]`. There's also no reason for `output_file` to be a file—what if you want to send it over the network instead or compress it (e.g. gzip) before writing it? You should accept a `&mut impl Write` instead.

```
let info = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
                   p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city,
                   p.state, p.zip_code);
```

is probably written better with a `fmt::Display` implementation.

In general, you should also not create `BufReader`s/`BufWriter`s within a function that reads or writes stuff. Leave the caller to do that.

[Final code](https://gist.github.com/lights0123/23b3cded6ee039db2ce0ac5c8677a37c):

````rust
//! # CSV Sorter
//!
//! This program reads in a CSV composed of information about people, such as
//! names and addresses. It then stores each entry into a struct, and those
//! structs into a vector. The vector is sorted by last name (or first, if
//! last names are identical) and the newly sorted data is written to an
//! output file.

use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::process;

/// Person struct to hold relevant data
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip_code: String,
}

impl Ord for Person {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        (
            self.last_name.to_lowercase(),
            self.first_name.to_lowercase(),
        )
            .cmp(&(
                other.last_name.to_lowercase(),
                other.first_name.to_lowercase(),
            ))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Person {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

///
/// Processes command-line arguments
///
/// # Description
/// This function processes the passed-in command line arguments and attempts
/// to open and create valid input/output files from the names given.
///
/// # Arguments
/// * `args` - A string array of command-line arguments.
///
/// # Returns
/// * A tuple of the input file and output file if they are found, else errors.
///
fn arg_parser(args: &[String]) -> Result<(File, File), &'static str> {
    // Exit if too many or too few arguments were passed
    if args.len() != 3 {
        return Err("Usage: 'cargo run [input file] [output file]");
    }

    // Get the input file
    let input_file = File::open(PathBuf::from("src").join(&args[1])).expect("Couldn't open file");
    let output_file =
        File::create(PathBuf::from("src").join(&args[2])).expect("Couldn't create file");

    // Return both files as a tuple
    Ok((input_file, output_file))
}

///
/// Builds a list of Person structs
///
/// # Description
/// This function reads the input file line by line and creates a Person
/// struct based on the line's contents. It then adds that struct to a vector
/// and repeats for every line in the file. The final vector contains every
/// Person struct read in from the file.
///
/// # Returns
/// * A vector of type Person containing all Person structs from the file.
fn build_person_vec(reader: &mut impl BufRead) -> Vec<Person> {
    let mut person_vec: Vec<Person> = Vec::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();

        let mut data = line.split(',').map(|s| s.trim());

        let p = Person {
            first_name: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
            last_name: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
            street: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
            city: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
            state: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
            zip_code: String::from(data.next().unwrap()),
        };
        person_vec.push(p);
    }
    person_vec
}

///
/// Writes data to the output file
///
/// Writes all Person structs to the output file, catching errors if the file
/// is not available to be written to.
fn write_to_file(person_vec: &[Person], output_file: &mut impl Write) {
    for p in person_vec {
        let info = format!(
            "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n",
            p.first_name, p.last_name, p.street, p.city, p.state, p.zip_code
        );

        output_file
            .write_all(info.as_bytes())
            .expect("Couldn't write to file");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    // Get the input and output files
    let (input_file, output_file) = arg_parser(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        eprintln!("\nError: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });

    let mut person_vec = build_person_vec(&mut BufReader::new(&input_file));

    person_vec.sort();

    write_to_file(&person_vec, &mut BufWriter::new(output_file));
}
```
````